# LLBLGEN: How can I get only necessary list of columns with FetchPolymorphic method?

Tags: llblgen

I have a list of tables and I'd like to select only necessary columns. How can I set filter witn FetchPolymorphic method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FetchPolymorphic](http://www.llblgen.com/documentation/2.6/Using%20the%20generated%20code/SelfServicing/gencode_usingentityclasses.htm) is done against an entity object when using SelfServicing so basically you are getting back an entity

C#

```
FamilyCarEntity car = (FamilyCarEntity)CompanyCarEntity.FetchPolymorphic(null, 4, null);
```

VB.NET

```
Dim car As FamilyCarEntity = CType(CompanyCarEntity.FetchPolymorphic(Nothing, 4, Nothing), FamilyCarEntity)
```

Once you have the entity object back (table or view) you can access it's properties (fields)

Using the [Adapter](http://www.llblgen.com/documentation/2.6/Using%20the%20generated%20code/Adapter/gencode_usingentityclasses_adapter.htm) is similar